# IE8 Bug with @media print? Table border disappears on pages greater than 1

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8, media

I have a page with an HTML table. When I use print preview in IE8, the table borders do not print starting on the 2nd page. So this is one and the same table, but it has a page break, and on the 2nd page there are no borders.

[image]

[image]

It seems to me that this ought to be a bug in IE that affects how the style sheets are applied across page breaks when *@media print* is used.

I will have to get to the bottom of this so that I can find a workaround. In the meantime, if somebody has seen this and know how to address it, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geez, why do I always have to run into these things?

This CSS does not work and shows (causes?) the above behavior:

```
@media print {
    #container, form { position: absolute; }
}
```

This CSS works as expected, the borders show up fine:

```
@media print {
    #container { position: absolute; }
    form { position: absolute; }
}
```

???

Comment: I was facing the same issue in chromium browser. It fixed the issue quite magically! Thank you :)